# solrnet server connection error. The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, solr, indexing, lucene.net, solrnet

Running on Tomcate windows xp with solrNet with using solrnet.dll and   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll and I am getting error The Remote server return an  error.(400) Bad Request.

when add content on this code

```
solr.Add(new Article()
    {
        _id = 1,
        _title = "My Laptop",
        _content = "My laptop is portable power station",
        _tags = new List<string>() {
        "laptop","computer","device"
        }

    });
```

i am using code below...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using SolrNet;
using SolrNet.Attributes;
using SolrNet.Commands.Parameters;
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;

namespace solrIndex_creator
{

 class Article
  {
    [SolrUniqueKey("id1")]
    public int _id { get; set; }

    [SolrField("title1")]
    public string _title { get; set; }

    [SolrField("content1")]
    public string _content { get; set; }

    [SolrField("tag1")]
    public List<string> _tags { get; set; }

    ISolrOperations<Article> solr;

   public void _write_Data()
    {
      Startup.Init<Article>("http://localhost:8080/solr/");
      solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Article>>();

       solr.Add(new Article()
        {
            _id = 1,
            _title = "My Laptop",
            _content = "My laptop is portable power station",
            _tags = new List<string>() {
            "laptop","computer","device"
            }

        });

       solr.Add(new Article()
        {
            _id = 2,
            _title = "my iphone",
            _content = "my iphone consumes power",
            _tags = new List<string>() {   
                "phone",   
                "apple",  
                "device"  
            }
        });

        solr.Add(new Article()
        {
            _id = 3,
            _title = "your blackberry",
            _content = "your blackberry has an alt key",
            _tags = new List<string>() {   
            "phone",   
            "rim",  
            "device"  
            }
        });
        solr.Commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is probably related to a mismatch with your Solr schema.xml `<fields>` settings and your Article class. You should be able to debug your program and examine the Bad Request error for more details on what the issue is. Or you can examine the server logs for Solr (in your hosting container e.g. Jetty, Tomcat) for more details as well.

Additionally, I would change your Tags property on the Article class to be the more generic `ICollection` like the multiValued examples on the [SolrNet Mapping wiki](https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Mapping).

Comment: thnks i have solved this error but i am getting error 'org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unknown commit parameter 'waitFlush''  when i am commiting index like solr.Commit()

Comment: This is an issue with earlier releases of the SolrNet library and Solr  4.X versions. You can download a later release of SolrNet from the build server - http://teamcity.codebetter.com/project.html?projectId=project36&guest=1 (Note: click on the Artifacts link to get to a downloadable zip file).

Comment: +1 for **download from  Build server**, I spent almost an hour figuring out the exception on `Commit`.